# tsql dynamic where

Tags: t-sql

I'm struggling with this procedure.

If its Monday thru Thursday I want everything 90 days ahead;

```
SELECT 
        PR.ClientID
        ,PR.NewDealEndDate
    INTO 
      #OriginalRenewalDetails
    FROM  
        Shiva.dbo.ProductRemortgage PR WITH (NOLOCK) 
        LEFT JOIN Shiva.dbo.ClientLead AS CL WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CL.OriginatorReferenceID) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PR.ClientID)
    WHERE -- 90 days from now. 
        PR.NewDealEndDate = DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))            
        AND CL.ClientID IS NULL
```

However if it is a Sunday I want the following changed in the Where clause. So that I get Friday and Saturdays results too.

```
WHERE -- 90 days from now. 
    PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 88, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))
    AND CL.ClientID IS NULL
```

I can't find an efficient way of doing this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for dynamic SQL or two separate queries here. Replacing the `**DAY = SUNDAY**` part with whatever logic you're currently using to determine the day is Sunday:

```
WHERE PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 
    CASE WHEN **DAY = SUNDAY** THEN 88 ELSE 90 END, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())) AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
AND CL.ClientID IS NULL;
```

You could also calculate the range beforehand, e.g.

```
DECLARE @start SMALLDATETIME, @end SMALLDATETIME;

SET @end = DATEADD(DAY, 90, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()));
SET @start = CASE WHEN **DAY = SUNDAY** THEN DATEADD(DAY, -2, @end) ELSE @end END;

WHERE PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN @start END @end
AND CL.ClientID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IF`.

pseudo:

```
if day = sunday
begin
   select with 88
end
else 
begin
   select with 90
end
```

---

OR change the WHERE clauses to something like:

```
WHERE (PR.NewDealEndDate = DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))
       AND CL.ClientID IS NULL AND Datepart(weekday, getdate()) <> 1)
      OR
      (PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 88, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE())) 
       AND DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))
       AND CL.ClientID IS NULL
       AND Datepart(weekday, getdate()) = 1)
```

Comment: Agreed, use an IF outside of the posted query to run one of two statements rather than overloading a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT PR.ClientID
        , PR.NewDealEndDate
INTO #OriginalRenewalDetails
FROM Shiva.dbo.ProductRemortgage PR WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN Shiva.dbo.ClientLead AS CL WITH (NOLOCK) 
    ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CL.OriginatorReferenceID) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), PR.ClientID)
WHERE CL.ClientID IS NULL
AND
(
    (
        PR.NewDealEndDate = DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))
        AND  Datepart(weekday, getdate()) <> 1 -- 1 is Sunday
    )
    OR
    (
        PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 88, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE())) 
        AND DATEADD(dd, 90, DATEDIFF(dd, 00, GETDATE()))
        AND Datepart(dayofweek, getdate()) = 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @adjustment int--SELECT DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) 
set @adjustment =
CASE 
    WHEN DATEPART(weekday, getdate()) 
    in (1,2,3,4,5) THEN 90     
ELSE 88
END

WHERE  
    PR.NewDealEndDate BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, @adjustment...
```